# How to use AFCoreImageSerializer in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I'd like to use the AFCoreImageSerializer class in my project but I'm not sure how to make it available to my project.  It doesn't appear to be included in the AFNetworking Cocoapod and I don't see a pod that would include it.

Is it just assumed you will include file directly in your project?